# I have a Citroen C4 Exclusive 2008 model 2L petrol engine not starting, turns over but no power to the coils

Tags: cranks-wont-run, citroen, immobilizer, citroen-c4

[image]

Hello, I have a 2008 Citroen C4 with a problem starting, it cranks but does not fire, my keys also stopped working at the same time and the lights, air conditioning, windows, multifunction display and radio all do not function with exception of the windows working for 5 seconds after the battery is reconnected.

After the keys have been in the ignition for 5 minutes all the displays go blank other than the tachometer.

I have attached a photo of the dash whilst cranking the engine, I have also checked the car with a scanner and the code displayed are (U0028) and (U0055).

I have tried to state as much info as I can. 
I have had a mobile mechanic out to have a look but he could not identify the problem and quoted me $800AUD to replace the coil pack and spark plugs however I do not agree that it is the coil pack and I am definitely not spending $800 on a maybe.

I have tried to bsi? Reboot or reset however this did nothing.

Comment: Did you check (or have checked) the battery and its connections, especially the ground terminal?  Many seemingly odd electrical issues can be caused by a bad battery or a bad ground connection.

Comment: You can temporarily use one cable of a jumper cable. Clamp one end onto the engine and the other end onto solid body metal in the engine compartment. This would bridge any poor ground. Use this temporary test procedure to bridge the battery negative terminal to engine or to body metal. A quick test can eliminate many questions.